# What is the default behaviour of a selector when the key set is sized 0?

Tags: java, css-selectors, nio

Just wondering what the normal behaviour of a [`Selector`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) in Java is when the key set is 0, since it's essentially a pointless operation (no keys available for selection). It might be that the operation happens anyway, even with a key set of 0. However, is it then possible for a channel key to be registered during selection and for the operation to be re-evaluated during selection?

If this isn't the case, then surely a selection operation with no keys would take an infinite amount of time? And in this case what happens to the other networking code? :) Maybe it's just a case of making sure that the key set is never 0. But I'd like to know since I've written a selector and need to make sure that it matches the official behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Selector` class is abstract and the actual operation is dependent upon what kind of `Selector` implementation the `SelectorProvider` actually returns. These depend upon the operating system.

If the implementation uses Sun's `sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl` as a base class (it too is abstract), then one can observe that the the `select()` methods synchronize on the public keys before invoking the abstract `doSelect()` method. The `register()` method also synchronizes on the public keys and therefore it is certainly possible that the register will have to wait for the select and the select will never complete because nothing is registered.

Unforunately it is all abstract classes so we cannot be sure. I do observe that the `Selector` documentation describes how to unstick a thread stuck in `select()` so presumably it is something that comes up often enough to be worth documenting, and therefore you are right to worry.

Comment: I think I fixed the underlying problem that was causing the issue seemingly caused by something related to this question. It turned out that I had mucked around with the SelectorImpl and my own Selector selection methods (my own copy) which need to transform 0 into -1, with -1 representing infinite wait. I had over-simplified things and taken this out accidentally. Also, the select method wasn't using -1 as an infinite wait so I had to change that. 0 was interpreted as doing the initial select and returning. So that seems to work okay now.

Comment: No, it doesn't depend on the implementation. It is specified in the Javadoc, and the implementation must comply. If there are no keys, there is nothing to become ready, so it must block forever, or until the timeout, depending on which method you called.